# MasterPage needs property from abstract generic class derived from System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two classes that are derived from an abstract generic class, which is derived from System.Web.UI.Page.  I have a System.Web.UI.MasterPage that may or may not be the master for either of my two derived page classes, or System.Web.UI.Page.

The problem is that the generic class has a property that I need to access in my MasterPage, but I don't know any elegant way to get it.

Here is an example...

Content types:

```
public abstract class Fruit
{
    public int ID { get; set; } //Just an identifier
}

public class Apple : Fruit {  }

public class Banana : Fruit {  }
```

Pages:

```
public abstract class FruitPage<T> : System.Web.UI.Page where T : Fruit
{
    public T MyFruit { get; set; } 
}

public class ApplePage : FruitPage<Apple> {  }

public class BananaPage : FruitPage<Banana> {  }
```

Master:

```
public partial class FoodMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (this.Page is FruitPage<Fruit>) //I know this is wrong
        {
            if ((this.Page as FruitPage<Fruit>).MyFruit.ID <= 0) //This too
            { 
                /*
                    I want to get here (this.Page being an ApplePage or BananaPage).  

                    Basically...  if ID<=0 then it is a new (unsaved) "fruit", 
                        and I need to change some MasterPage GUI accordingly. 
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code you placed in `FoodMaster` really belongs in FruitPage...then you won't have that problem.  It never applies in any other case.

Comment: I thought about that too but, and I probably should have mentioned this, I'm using nested masters.  `FoodMaster` is actually the "parent" of, say `FoodFruitMaster`.  I thought about adding a method to `FoodMaster` and calling that method from the page, but it would have to bubble up through `FoodFruitMaster`.  Which I thought was sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Any problem in computer science can be solved with another level of indirection."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

```
public class FruitPage : System.Web.UI.Page {
   public Fruit MyInnerFruit { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class FruitPage<T> : FruitPage where T : Fruit
{
   public T MyFruit { 
     get { return (T)MyInnerFruit; } 
     set { MyInnerFruit = value; } 
   }
}

public partial class FoodMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
       base.OnLoad(e);

       var fruitPage = this.Page as FruitPage;
       if (fruitPage != null && fruitPage.MyInnerFruit.ID <= 0) {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

You could also shadow `MyInnerFruit`/`MyFruit` - but it's easier to understand without.

If you're using .NET 4, you can also use a covariant interface to basically allow casts from `FruitPage<Apple>` to `FruitPage<Fruit>`:

```
public interface IFruitPage<out T> where T : Fruit {
    public T MyFruit { get; }
}

public class FruitPage<T> : Page, IFruitPage<T> where T : Fruit {
    public T MyFruit { get; set; }
}

public class FoodMaster : MasterPage {
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
       base.OnLoad(e);

       var fruitPage = this.Page as IFruitPage<Fruit>;
       if (fruitPage != null && fruitPage.MyFruit.ID <= 0) {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "a covariant interface to basically allow casts from `FruitPage<Apple>` to `FruitPage<Fruit>`"

This is the ticket.  Thank you!